# Timer in SwiftUI works in background for simulator but not on real phone

Tags: timer, background, swiftui

I am making a timer app on swiftui and when I run my app on the simulator, the timer works fine and runs in the background. When I test it on my phone, the timer stops when the app goes into the background. Also, when my app goes into the background on my phone, this message appears:

Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: If your problem is about background issue.
What ever the real device or simulator you used. This message must be shown on the console.

Comment: My issue is that when I try to run the timer in the background, it stops running.

Comment: Have same issue. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this way to run something and change your UI stuff on background thread:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    print("Background Thread is running")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("You can change UI stuff here.")
        label.text = "Done." //UIKit
        self.myLabelTxt = "Done." //SwiftUI's string state variable 
    }
}
```

Hope it will help!